# Django Template Ternary Operator

Tags: python, django, templates, ternary-operator

I was wondering if there was a ternary operator (condition ? true-value : false-value) that could be used in a Django template.  I see there is a python one (true-value if condition else false-value) but I'm unsure how to use that inside a Django template to display the html given by one of the values.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Why would you need a ternary operator within a template? `{% if %}` and `{% else %}` are all you need.

Or you could try the `firstof` tag:

```
{% firstof var1 var2 var3 %}
```

which outputs the first one of var1, var2 or var3 which evaluates to a True value.

Comment: I suppose you're right, I'll just use if/else.  Just addicted to ternary I guess.

Comment: I would like to see ternary support, too.

Comment: I tend to disagree with Daniel.  I recently converted a django template to a simple javascript template: `{% if data_complete %}{{ data }}{% else %}{{ something_else }}{% endif %}` became  `<%= data_complete ? data : something_else %>`  ... the second is so much more compact and elegant.  It would be nice if there was an equivalent in django.

Comment: "why would you" ... well, to do something in 30 sec instead of 10mn, for instance. Django templating isn't so developer-friendly, it's not always a good thing to have to do stuff in the view instead of the template.

Answer (score 123):

You can use the yesno filter:

```
{{ value|yesno:"yeah,no,maybe" }}
```

You can learn more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno)

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for the answer. I knew this existed, but couldn't remember.

Comment: Very nice and simple, but when I want to use some variables it seems this filter is not applicable. For instance I would like to use `{{ expr_or_value | yesno : "the string", other_variable_value }}`

Comment: This should be the selected answer! This is exactly what's being asked.

Comment: The documentation doesn't state it but you can also do `{{ value|yesno: "checked," }}` if you want to use this for presetting checkboxes

Answer (score 30):

Just because they haven't been mentioned here yet: the built in template tags `default`, and `default_if_none` can be useful in simple circumstances:

> #### default
>
> If value evaluates to False, uses the given default. Otherwise, uses the value.
>
> For example:
>
> `{{ value|default:"nothing" }}`
>
> If value is "" (the empty string), the output will be nothing.
>
> #### default_if_none
>
> If (and only if) value is None, uses the given default. Otherwise, uses the >value.
>
> Note that if an empty string is given, the default value will not be used. Use >the default filter if you want to fallback for empty strings.
>
> For example:
>
> `{{ value|default_if_none:"nothing" }}`
>
> If value is None, the output will be the string "nothing".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#default

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590198/django-setting-for-default-template-tag-output-when-variable-is-none

Comment: Too bad this doesn't work for unknown attributes, would have been nice.

Answer (score 5):

I've just implemented the ternary operator for Django as a tag, see https://github.com/alexei/django-template-extensions
You can use it as:

```
{% ?: exp1 exp2 exp3 %}
{% ?: exp1 exp2 %}
```

Or:

```
{% iif exp1 exp2 exp3 %}
{% iif exp1 exp2 %}
```

I figured out that it makes more sense than the `yesno` filter, even though it's really not that Pythonic.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Solves the issue that I can't pass context variables to `|yesno`

Answer (score 4):

You don't. The Django `{% if %}` templatetag has only just started supporting `==`, `and`, etc. `{% if cond %}{% else %}{% endif %}` is as compact as it gets for now.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if the python and/or trick would work?

```
condition and true_value or false_value
```

behaves a like the ternary operator - outputs true_value if condition evaluates to True, and false_value if not.

Comment: I learnt recently that  `true_value if condition else false_value` is also valid Python syntax, and it's much more readable -- will check if it works in templates...

Comment: That was the first thing I tried; I'm surprised it doesn't work.