# Django setting for default template tag output when variable is None?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am looking for a django setting or programmatic way to make all django template tags show the empty string when the value is None. For example, imagine that I have some django template:

```
{{cat}} chases {{mouse}}
```

if both cat and mouse are None, it will render as:

```
None chases None
```

I am aware that I can set each one using `{{cat|default:""}}` or `{{mouse|default_if_none:""}}`

However, I am looking for some sort of setting that would allow me to set the default for all tags, without explicitly adding `|default:""` to every tag.

I am also aware of a setting called `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`. However, this setting applies only to invalid strings. None is considered valid.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No such thing exists. That's why the [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#default) and [`default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) filters exist. This is a *feature*; it makes you think about what you're doing instead of relying on some behavior that would often times be misleading. If there's a potential for a variable to be `None`, then you should plan for that contingency. If the variable should always have *some* value, then the "None" indicates something is not right. If the default was to just render a blank string, then you would not know whether the value is not defined or is actually a blank string. Write coherent code and forget about shortcuts.

Comment: Lame. What happened to the "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"? I'm afraid this is not very Pythonic and not at all following DRY — writing `default_if_none` everywhere!. To circumvent this "feature", `forms.fields.CharField` is never returning None, cause it's better to store empty strings DB… yeah, sure :P — sorry for the bragging, I couldn't help myself.

Comment: @WooYek: Another point is taking logic out of the template. I can probably count on one hand the number of times I've *actually* used `default` or `default_if_none` in a template, largely because I plan my models and views such that there's always *some* value returned, or it's in an if block in the template. Simply, if you have those tags scattered all over your template, I'd say it's more your failure than Django's.

Comment: The same argument could be applied to the removal of `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` setting, yet it exits… Do the Django dev 's do not plan they views so they do not contain missing fields!? I do rarely use `default_if_none`, but even more rarely I set to something else than empty string. I'm just saying: Its — the missing setting — not there because there was no much demand, due to not many places — in django — that "empty" means `None` type. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: And the eternal "template logic" is so wrong, are you saying that the DATE_FORMAT setting is wrong to? Anyway this is not the please, for such discussion. Again, sorry about the brag, for me it's EOT.

Answer (score 4):

"Explicit is better than implicit"

Think of how enraged you would be when things wouldn't render properly because you forgot that you had enabled the magic "render everything with a false value as a null string" setting.

If you find you're using the `default_if_none` filter a lot, you might want to consider changing casting `None` to `''` BEFORE it's passed to the template.

Your template will be simpler, and you will have **explicitly** made this decision to stringify null values.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick, put it somewhere in the initialization code, for eg. in `wsgi.py`

```
# Patch template Variable to output empty string for None values
from django.template.base import Variable
_resolve_lookup = Variable._resolve_lookup
def new_resolve_lookup(self, *args, **kwargs):
    o = _resolve_lookup(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return o or u""
Variable._resolve_lookup = new_resolve_lookup
```

Comment: This actually does the job, I placed the code in a middleware file, but outside of the class