# populating form from database : shorthand print/if AND concatenate

Tags: python, django, templates

so im writing a edit form , basically im showing the form and if user has already fill it i want to populate the from with database stored values

my view :

```
def edit(request):
    try:
       account =  Accounts.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    except Accounts.DoesNotExist :
        account = False
    return render(request , 'account/edit.html' , {'cuAcc':account})
```

so in my template i have w fild for name

```
 <input type="text" name="name" value="">
```

i want to fill it with database stored name if exist so i've tried these

```
 <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ cuAcc.name if cuAcc else '' }}">
```

didnt work

```
 <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ cuAcc.name or '' }}">
```

also didnt work and iof found this

```
{{ cuAcc|yesno:"yeah,no" }}
```

which might work but i have no idea how should i should concatenate  `cuAcc.name` and empty character in there

so whats the usual method in this situations ? im coming from php and there we have something like

```
{{ cuAcc ? cuAcc.name : '' }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Template Ternary Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110166/django-template-ternary-operator)

Comment: @e4c5 i've coverd answers on that question , they didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need any checks, just put this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ cuAcc.name }}">
```

if user has `name`, it fills it, otherwise it doesnot.

or you may want [default_if_none](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none):

```
def edit(request):
    try:
       account =  Accounts.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    except Accounts.DoesNotExist :
       account = None #<---- None instead of False
    return render(request , 'account/edit.html' , {'cuAcc': account})
```

template

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ cuAcc.name|default_if_none:'Please enter your name' }}">
```

Comment: thanx , but what if i want to add something other than empty space like `pleas enter your name` ... btw this worked , so python doesnt care if printed value doesn't exist ?  i mean this in most languages would cuz an error

Comment: @hretic django renders `None` as empty to template.

Comment: so anything that doesn't exist is None ! thats why i dont see error ,  i get it now thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an empty Account in the except clause like this:

```
def edit(request):
    try:
       account =  Accounts.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    except Accounts.DoesNotExist :
        account = Accounts()
    return render(request , 'account/edit.html' , {'cuAcc':account})
```

and the template should have:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ cuAcc.name }}">
```

I hope this works.